# При попытке вывода переменной выдается "Missing operator or semicolon"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Я хотел написать простое арифметическое вычисление в делфи.
Но выводит ошибку:

> [Error] Project1.dpr(10): Missing operator or semicolon

Вот мой код:

```
program Project1;

uses
  SysUtils;
var x,y:real;
begin
write('x='); readln(x);
if(x>1) then y:=cos(x)/(x*x*x+3*sin(x)+8)
else y:=x*x*x+3*sin(x)+8
writeln('y=', y:0:3);
Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не хватает `;` после блока else. Чтобы не путаться, запомните - всегда окружайте блоки кода операторными скобками `begin` и `end`, даже если это блок из одного вызова:

```
program Project1;

uses
  SysUtils;
var x,y:real;
begin
   write('x='); readln(x);
   if(x>1) then 
   begin
       y:=cos(x)/(x*x*x+3*sin(x)+8);
   end
   else 
   begin
       y:=x*x*x+3*sin(x)+8;
   end;
  writeln('y=', y:0:3);
   Readln;
end.
```

Оно же на [ideone](http://ideone.com/yvnXSK)

Comment: Я скопировал ваш код и компилировал выдается такое ошибка http://sh.uploads.ru/3bcPB.png

Comment: @ErkinPardayev понятия не имею, что вы там компилировали, но точно не мой код. Ideone все прекрасно компилирует.

Comment: Спасибо. По моему мне надо изменить компилятор

Comment: @ErkinPardayev - Delphi 7  хоть и старая, но не в маразме. Таких проблем быть не должно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так будет правильным как с логической точки зрения, так и с точки зрения форматирования:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} // Инструкция для Делфи, что это консольное приложение

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  x, y: real;    
begin
  // Ждем ввода значения Х от пользователя
  write('x=');
  readln(x);

  // Логика программы
  if (x > 1) then
    y := cos(x) / (x * x * x + 3 * sin(x) + 8)
  else
    y := x * x * x + 3 * sin(x) + 8; // <-- Ошибка была здесь, пропущена ;

  // Показываем результат
  writeln('y=', y:0:3);
  readln;
end.
```

Обратите внимание, как правильное форматирование позволяет сразу увидеть всю программу и заметить в ней ошибки.

P.S. На всякий случай, тригонометрические функции типа `cos` ожидают на входе угол в радианах, так что если пользователь вводит число в градусах, вам будет нужно его перевести в радианы.